# Tablesorter doesn't sort fields with %

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

For some reason when fields contain a special character like `%` the sorting fails altogether.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/fEWdz/4/) shows how column A works without percentage normally.

```
<tbody id="search_result">
    <tr>
        <td>AAA 0</td>
      <td>39.90</td>
      <td>29 Dec 2012</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
```

But as soon as `%` comes in it fails --> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/fEWdz/2/)

```
<tbody id="search_result">
    <tr>
        <td>AAA 0%</td>
      <td>39.90</td>
      <td>29 Dec 2012</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example

```
$(function() { 

  $.extend($.tablesorter.themes.bootstrap, { 
    // these classes are added to the table. To see other table classes available, 
    // look here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables 
    table      : 'table', 
    header     : 'bootstrap-header', // give the header a gradient background 
    footerRow  : '', 
    footerCells: '', 
    icons      : '', // add "icon-white" to make them white; this icon class is added to the <i> in the header 
    sortNone   : 'bootstrap-icon-unsorted', 
    sortAsc    : 'icon-chevron-up', 
    sortDesc   : 'icon-chevron-down',
    active     : '', // applied when column is sorted 
    hover      : '', // use custom css here - bootstrap class may not override it 
    filterRow  : '', // filter row class 
    even       : '', // odd row zebra striping 
    odd        : ''  // even row zebra striping 
  }); 

  // call the tablesorter plugin and apply the uitheme widget 
  $("#tab_open_deals").tablesorter({ 
    theme : "bootstrap", // this will  

    widthFixed: true, 

    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon! 

    // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file 
    // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget) 
    widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ], 

    widgetOptions : { 
      // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above 
      // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden 
      zebra : ["even", "odd"], 

      // reset filters button 
      filter_reset : ".reset", 

      // set the uitheme widget to use the bootstrap theme class names 
      // uitheme : "bootstrap" 

    } 
  }) 
  .tablesorterPager({ 

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below 
    container: $(".pager"), 

    // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page 
    cssGoto  : ".pagenum", 

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables. 
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled. 
    removeRows: false, 

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; 
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows} 
    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})' 

  }); 

});

$(document).ready(function() {


});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vCTHw/575/)

Greetings

Comment: +1 many thanks, it seems to be working. Part of the solution is `0: { sorter: "text" },`  but there is another thing that I don;t see you have done. Still investigating.

Comment: @Kave, that's all you should need... here is [your demo updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fEWdz/5/), and [here is MG_Bautista's demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vCTHw/576/) updated to use the jQuery UI theme (that was an older version demo), it needed the `headerTemplate` option to include an `{icon}`.